# Function return: PHP

Tags: php, function, theorem, pythagorean

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I can't get `$c` to output correctly.

```
<?php
    function pythThm($a, $b){
        $a2 = pow($a, 2);
        $b2 = pow($b, 2);
        $c = sqrt($a2 + $b2);
        if(is_int($c)){
            return $c;
        }
    }

    echo pythThm(3, 4);
    // Outputs nothing. it should be 5
?>
```

**Solution to problem:**

```
<?php
    function pythThm($a, $b){
        $a2 = pow($a, 2);
        $b2 = pow($b, 2);
        $c = sqrt($a2 + $b2);
        if($c - round($c) == 0){
            return $c;
        }
    }

    echo pythThm(4, 4);
    // Returns nothing
    echo pythThm(3,4);
    // Returns 5
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqrt` returns a `float`, which is not an `int`, so your function returns nothing. Just leave off the `is_int` check?

Comment: hmm..I need only the `$c` those which are integers for this problem.  However, I think a simple `if($c - round($c) == 0)` would do the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`sqrt` always returns a float. Your *if* statement condition is always false.

If you want to do the check, do this:

```
$i = (int) $c;

if($c == $i) return $c
```

This casts the float to an int, and if the float `$c` and the int `$i` are equal, then it will return.

Answer (score 1):

`sqrt` returns a `float`, and that's why `is_int` is always false.

If you really want to check if it's an integer, you can use:

```
if ((int)$c == $c)
    return $c;
```

Comment: yep, i thought of a similar check after seeing the first comment.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

**That is typo in your result**

```
function pythThm($a, $b){
    $a2 = pow($a, 2);
    $b2 = pow($b, 2);
    $c = sqrt($a2 + $b2);
    return (int)$c;
}

echo pythThm(3, 4);
```

Comment: What *is* the typo? What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function pythThm($a, $b){
        $a2 = pow($a, 2);
        $b2 = pow($b, 2);
        $c = sqrt($a2 + $b2);
        return $c;
    }

    echo pythThm(3, 4);
    // Outputs nothing. It should be 5
?>
```

Comment: this would return all values as integers...whether they were integers or not.

Comment: There's no need for the `is_int()` check, it will be always true, because of the cast of `$c` to int...